# LinQ max Date in one Query Optimized

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
Decimal initialBalance;
DateTime dailyDate = ctx.DailyBalances.Max(c => c.DailyDate);
          if (dailyDate != null)
              initialBalance = ctx.DailyBalances.Where(c => c.DailyDate == dailyDate).Select(c => c.FinalBalance).FirstOrDefault();
            else
                initialBalance = 0;

            return initialBalance;
```

Nevertheless i've been trying to get ways to optimized it,making one query instead of one... any sugestion??

Comment: This code doesn't make sense as written: dailyDate will never be null... (DateTime can't be null)

Comment: sorry your right just but i was wondering about the whole issue of taking the max and then getting the balance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `OrderByDescending` and take the first record:

```
initialBalance = ctx.DailyBalances
   .OrderByDescending(c => c.DailyDate)
   .Select(c => c.FinalBalance)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

This type of query is optimized in SQL Server so that it doesn't require an O(n log(n)) sort of the entire table. If there is an index on `DailyDate` it will find the last row in the index, and without an index it will use an optimized algorithm called [`Top N Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189054.aspx) that runs in linear time.

However this query will be O(n log(n)) in LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Pretty sure you mean .OrderByDescending(c => c.DailyDate).

Comment: You are awesome.